# Change text input to select option input with scaffolding

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am follow this tutorial to learn ASP.NET 5 MVC6

http://docs.asp.net/projects/mvc/en/latest/getting-started/first-mvc-app/adding-model.html#scaffolding-a-controller

By scaffolding a controller, I have create function which can add new movie to database. However, the movie Genre field is string.

http://docs.asp.net/projects/mvc/en/latest/_images/movies.png

I want to change it to select option.

Can scaffolding do it? 
If not, how do I modify the code to make Genre field to be select options field (Romantic, Action,..)

Thanks

Comment: you have to fill select box wih viewbag

Comment: This lik will hep you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20563801/bind-dropdownlistfor-with-the-viewbag